# Inertia + Laravel - Reload post page and keep the result

Tags: laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

I've this route code:

```php
// route.php
Route::post(
    '/page',
    [App\Http\Controllers\PageController::class, 'index']
)->name('page.details');
```

My controller:

```php
// PageController.php
public function index(Request $request)
{
    return Inertia::render('Page/PageDetails', [
        "name" => $request->name,
        "overview" => $request->overview,
        "url" => $request->url
    ]);
}
```

It's working, fine, but If I try to reload ( F5 ) it's return an error 500.

Have some way to I reload page and get the latest data? [ name, overview, url ].

Comment: If you're pressing `F5` you're making a `GET` request. If you don't have a `Route::get` to the page you're refreshing, you'll have troubles.

Comment: @MatheusDal'Pizzol I knew that, but how I can add a get route without lose the data?

Comment: My point was that, if you're pressing `F5`, you're not going to hit the route you registered, because you registered it with `Route::post`. You need to have a `Route::get` for that. Now, if want to submit the data with `POST`, you'll need to have a redirect to another route which will be registered via Route::get. Is this clear for you?